# Custom classloader fails after upgrading sbt from 0.12.2 to 0.13+

Tags: scala, sbt, classloader

After updating my `build.properties` to use sbt 0.13+ I can no longer dynamically load case classes at runtime.

With sbt 0.12.2 I was able to use a custom [classloader](https://github.com/julianpeeters/case-class-generator/blob/master/src/main/java/DynamicClassLoader.java), but now with sbt 0.13.2 I get an [error](https://gist.github.com/julianpeeters/892bf83ad9defea3a160): `caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product`

Here's a [runnable example](https://github.com/julianpeeters/case-class-generator). Running `sbt test` will show the error.

What changed in sbt 0.13 that puts my dynamic classloading shenanigans to an end, and how might I fix this?

Thanks for taking a look!

-Julian

#### Edit:

Using sbt 0.13.7-M4 partially solves this problem. `sbt run` succeeds, while `sbt test` gives a different [error](https://gist.github.com/julianpeeters/210d54a211d3c10a767e), where it seems that the dynamically loaded class in each test is being loaded twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Loading twice" error in Test was due to me not putting my setup code within the Specs2 expectation.

In addition, I need to use a different classloader in sbt 0.13+ : Issue was due to using the wrong classloader.

First I tried `ClassLoader loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();`, but then that broke.

Next, with sbt 0.12.2, I tried `ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();`, but that broke with sbt 0.13+.

Now I'm using a dummy class to probe and get a classloader a la `probe.getClass().getClassLoader()`,
and that seems to have solved the problem.